# Error while retrieving records from Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, ssis, dynamics-crm, dataverse

I'm getting below error while retrieving records from `account` table in Dynamics CRM. Error message is in the screenshot below.

[image]

Could you please guide me what I'm doing wrong here.

Strange thing is that it is working in a console app. Hence I'm assuming the credentials are correct. But this is not working in SSIS Script Task. I'm a Data Engineer and doesn't have much experience in C#. One more story: This was previously working on other server and that server is decommissioned now. We've got a new server. The moment I executed he code on new server it gave me an error that the assembly was missing. I added the Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.dll in GAC and now it is giving this error.

Comment: Most likely, the response from your `.Execute()` call is `NULL`, so you cannot just dereference the `.UserId` from  it.... read back the response, check for `response != null`, and only if that's true, **then** use `response.UserId` to get the user id.... basic defensive programming 101  ....

Comment: check if with clientid&clientsecret authentication your code works

Comment: Most likely the **organizationService** is not ready. You can use **organizationService.IsReady** to check the connection status and use **organizationService.LastCrmError** or **organizationService.LastCrmException** to get error info.

Comment: Post the code and exception as *text* in the question itself. The error tells you that you tried to call a property or method on a `null` value. Are you *sure* that `Execute` returned anything?

Comment: @marc_s

Strange thing is that it is working in  a console app. Hence I'm assuming the credentials are correct. But this is not working in SSIS Script Task. I'm a Data Engineer and doesn't have much experience in C#. 

One more story: This was previously working on other server and that server is decommissioned now. We've got a new server. 

The moment I executed he code on new server it gave me an error that the assembly was missing. I added the Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.dll in GAC and now it is giving this error.

Comment: I would try it out in Postman before jumping into the actual code, so that you can ensure your credentials are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the passed credentials are not valid.

Use the `CrmServiceClient.IsReady` property to find out if a working connection has been established. If not, property `LastCrmError` should give you a clue about what went wrong. Property `LastCrmException` may also be useful.

```cs
var client = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

if (!client.IsReady)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed on first attempt. " + client.LastCrmError);

    // Try again, but now with login prompt. (LoginPrompt=Always)
    ...
```